# Mysql remote connection over wireless adhoc

Tags: mysql, wifi, remote-access

Good day.

I have a database on my laptop that I would like my class mate to connect to remotely.  We set up an ad-hoc wireless connection but everytime he tries to test the connection to my database it always fails and we get a "Failed to connect to MySQL at 192.168.1.2:3307 with user root".

We tried connecting with root, a user that we created on my mysql, I just don't know anymore. I want to cry now.

Please help

Comment: you have to close any firewalls or open the port for connection

Comment: Just checking. The port is `3307` or `3306`?

Comment: The port is 3307 since im running from mysql 5.6

Comment: I was able to connect, I figured my firewall was blocking the port. Thanks